How to retain scroll position at top when navigating between pages?
I'm encountering an issue in my ReactJS application where, upon navigating to a new page, the page automatically scrolls down to a position below the top of the page instead of starting from the top (generally it takes scroll position from the previous page). This behavior is inconsistent with typical page navigation where the new page should load from the top.
I've looked into possible solutions but haven't found one that works for me. I found a lot on the internet but found a solution below that didn't work for me. How can I ensure that when navigating between pages, the new page consistently loads from the top instead of scrolling down?
const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    };
  }, [history]);

  return null;
};

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const {pathname} = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
};

Neither of the above solutions worked out for me.

Add the following line to some place relevant in the application (like in the index file or a router configuration file etc.)
window.history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'

If you're staying within your application (not reloading or refreshing the page, so the navigation is happening internally and inside react-router-dom), here's a helpful link - react-router scroll to top on every transition

@hn791 thanks for replying, added on App component inside useEffect, but not getting as expected

No, not inside useEffect or any component, inside the file. Just after doing all the imports. This tells the browser to not restore scroll position automatically.

Can you please provide me a simple example for this

Are you rendering that 'ScrollToTop' component inside your Router? If so, can you tell me how or show me the code? I'm sensing there is something that you probably are missing which is causing the scrolling to not occur!





                        {
                            Object.values(r).map(x =>
                                )
                        }
                        



Yes, rendered inside the Router. please check the code in above comment.

Your ScrollToTop component returns null, but you're passing children to it. Is this the right code?

Yes this is the code

Based on your previous definitions of ScrollToTop, your Switch component isn't supposed to be rendered (<Switch> { Object.values(r).map(x => <Route key={x.path} exact={true} path={x.path} component={x.component}></Route>) } <Redirect to={Routes.Home.path} /> </Switch>). Because Switch is provided as a children of ScrollToTop - whereas ScrollToTop doesn't render any children (returns null). Is your application rendering your routes properly?

Yes ScrollToTop not rendering the components cause of return null in ScrollToTop. And changed the scrollToTop as
const ScrollToTop = ({ children }: any) => {
const { pathname } = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, [pathname]);
return children;

}
But this also does not render the component from Top

I see! At this point, it's not apparent what's causing the problem. If your code is public, I can take a look at it. Else, you can try to provide further information that you think could help to debug your problem.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Try destructing pathname like this
const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const {pathname} = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
};

or
check and remove somewhere in your css files if you have
scroll-behavior: auto

